# Flash AS3 security errors attempting to load chromeless YouTube

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube

I am getting flash-base security errors when attempting to load a chromeless YouTube swf...

```
Warning: Domain www.youtube.com does not explicitly specify a meta-policy, but Content-Type of policy file http://www.youtube.com/crossdomain.xml is 'text/x-cross-domain-policy'.  Applying meta-policy 'by-content-type'.

Error: Request for resource at http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3 by requestor from http://... is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3 halted - not permitted from http://...
```

I've attempted all relevant variations of Security.loadPolicyFile and Security.allowDomain, but I continue to get these errors.

If I ignore these trace errors (I get no callback errors from the Loader) and attempt to use the player (via loader.content during the Loader's Event.INIT), then any attempts to access the YouTube APIs causes a crash.

If I look at my player (Object) variable in a debugger, I see that it is actually a com.goggle.youtube.application::SwfProxy which is derived from Sprite.  Outside of the standard Sprite vars and functions, it contains enableJsApi = false, loader = null, and player = "http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/apiplayer3-vfljSpMoI.swf"

But attempts to call functions such as player.setSize or player.loadVideoByUrl will cause a crash such as...

```
Exception thrown (TypeError: Error #1006: setSize is not a function.
```

Please advise.

Comment: OK, I solved half of the problem... I am now able to call setSize and loadVideoByUrl without crashing.  I was attempting to use the player during the Loader's Event.INIT instead of the player's "onReady" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked to remove the errors was specifying... LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain())

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with the Chromeless player before and gotten these errors. They are so frustrating. A number of the errors can be ignored because YouTube still hasn't renewed their default policy file.

Whevener you try to add any mouse event listeners to the gadget directly you will get errors that will cripple the runtime process. What I had to do to add mouse interactivity was to add a sprite above the movie clip with a hole where their logo shows up (so that someone can still click their logo) and then add event listeners to your own srite.

Hope this helps.